# Component render() triggered after history.push but page is blank

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want the user to be redirected to the resources list after he deleted an item on its show page. I 've read a lot of SO Q&A on the topic, but I think I have a different issue as my routes and component got hit the right way after history.push

I tracked code execution through debugger till component render and still don't understand why nothing is returned

Here are my routes in my App component (wrapped this way`<Router><App /></Router>`) component :

```
<Route component={AppHeader} />
{["/articles/:id/edit", "/articles/new"].map((path, index) =>
  <Route key={index} exact path={path} component{ArticleForm}/>
)}
<Route exact path="/articles/:id" component={Article}/>
{["/", "/articles"].map((path, index) =>
  <Route key={index} exact path={path} component{ArticlesList}/>
)}
```

I use redux so Router and ArticleList are exported this way :

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component))
```

In AppHeader component, a delete button is provided, if user is on show or edit page. When clicking on the link, following method is triggered :

```
class AppHeader extends Component {
...
  deleteArticle = async () => {
    await ajaxHelpers.ajaxCall('DELETE',`/articles/${this.state.currentArticleID}`, {}, this.state.token)
    this.props.history.push("/")
  }
...
}
```

Then Route with ArticlesList is triggered and should render this component. Here is what happens (breakpoints all the way in render methods):

- URL is updated
- Router is rendered
- App header is rendered
- Article list is rendered
- Article list re-rendered with fecth from API (state populated with list)
- Article list re-rendered with componentDidUpdate

BUT page stays blank ... I am using this.props.history.push("/") in other components and it works fine (list get re-rendered and displayed). See blank page and console.logs :
[image]

If I manually reload the page, it renders normally.

What is preventing any component to be displayed (DOM is nearly empty, I only get my empty `<div id="root"></div>`) in this case ?

Comment: Maybe there is a typo, but you are calling withRouter(connect(...)(Router))?

Comment: Actually the routes are wrapped in an App component  ```<Router><App></Router>```, thus I use ```withRouter(connect(...)(Component))``` where component stands for App or ArticlesList

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing ,to displaying Article list use filter to update list state

```
deleteArticle = async () => {
  await ajaxHelpers.ajaxCall('DELETE',`/articles/${this.state.currentArticleID}`, {}, this.state.token)
this.setState({articleList:articleList.filter((list)=> list.id!==this.state.currentArticleID)})
}
```

Change :

```
this.props.history.push("/")
```

To :

```
this.setState({articleList:articleList.filter((list)=> list.id!==this.state.currentArticleID)})
```

Comment: This wont help as the deleteArticle method is in AppHeader component and has no access to articleList. The articleList is populated in ArticleList componentDidMount() through a fetch from an API. This actually happens, as you can see in the screenshot, an array of 3 articles is passed to ArticleList component

Comment: This can be help if your ARTICLE LIST and delete functionality  both are  in same page.
Delete button is there where you are showing article list ,Right?

Comment: As stated in the question Delete button is in AppHeader component, not in ArticleList component. As stated in the question as well, I want the delete button to be provided on the Article show or edit pages, not in the List. Even if it was in the List, the list is updated on componentDidMount() so updating the state right after delete would anyway be overridden by componentDidmount()